# “Array.prototype.slice: 'this' is not a JavaScript object” error fore each in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting this error message only in IE8, and I don't know how to convert the existing function for IE8 compatibility.

```
(function() {
  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tabs')).forEach(function(el) {
    new CBPFWTabs(el);
  });
})();

CBPFWTabs.prototype._init = function() {
  this.tabs = [].slice.call(this.el.querySelectorAll('nav > ul > li'));
  this.items = [].slice.call(this.el.querySelectorAll('.content-wrap > section'));

  this.current = -1; // current index
  this._show(); // show current content item
  this._initEvents();
};
```

Comment: At which line are you getting the error?

Comment: [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tabs')).forEach(function(el) {

Comment: IE8 is dead...! [0.73% marketshare worldwide](http://gs.statcounter.com/browser-version-partially-combined-market-share/desktop/worldwide/#monthly-201606-201706) you should [stop supporting](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsforbusiness/end-of-ie-support) it